# Get average number of days per year greater than a daily mean value with Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I create the following Pandas Series, which contains some daily measurement over 10 years at three different stations

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

stations = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dates    = pd.date_range(start = '2000-01-01', end = '2009-12-31')
index    = [(stations[i], dates[j]) for i in range(len(stations)) for j in range(len(dates))]
index    = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index, names=["station", "date"])

x        = np.random.random(len(index))

df       = pd.Series(index = index, data = x)
```

Resulting in a Series that looks like:

```
>>> df
station  date      
a        2000-01-01    0.736381
         2000-01-02    0.203178
         2000-01-03    0.640063
         2000-01-04    0.942664
         2000-01-05    0.953994
                         ...   
c        2009-12-27    0.713189
         2009-12-28    0.800085
         2009-12-29    0.033923
         2009-12-30    0.972547
         2009-12-31    0.387804
Length: 10959, dtype: float64
```

Now, for each station, I want to calculate the average number of days per year that have measurement values which are greater than the daily mean on a given day.

I know I can calculate the daily mean value for each station like this:

```
daily_mean = df.groupby(['station',index.get_level_values('date').dayofyear]).mean()

>>> daily_mean
station  date
a        1       0.529211
         2       0.432048
         3       0.438350
         4       0.629226
         5       0.523919
                   ...   
c        362     0.524537
         363     0.346734
         364     0.423349
         365     0.433348
         366     0.316085
Length: 1098, dtype: float64
```

But after this step, I can't figure out what to do.
Basically I want to do something like:

```
df['a','2000-01-01'] > daily_mean['a', 1]
df['a','2000-01-02'] > daily_mean['a', 2]
...
df['a','2000-12-31'] > daily_mean['a', 365]
```

...Then calculate how many days that year were above average, and do this for each year, and then take the mean number of days above average across all years. And then do that for each station.

I could probably do what I want with some painful looping, but I figure there might be a more Pandas-y way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can compare a value for a column to the within-group column average with the following pattern.

This technique uses [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) method on a grouped dataframe, which will yield a result of the same length as the original grouped dataframe, rather than condensing rows. As an illustrative example:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], 10), 'B': np.random.beta(2, 9, 10)})
test
```

Out

```
   A         B
0  b  0.099245
1  c  0.081244
2  b  0.239556
3  b  0.211645
4  c  0.256624
5  c  0.091649
6  b  0.213261
7  a  0.327473
8  a  0.240529
9  c  0.235569
```

```
test.groupby('A').B.mean()
```

Out

```
A
a    0.284001
b    0.190927
c    0.166271
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Using transform:

```
test['within_A_mean'] = test.groupby('A').B.transform('mean')
test.sort_values('A')
```

Out

```
   A         B  within_A_mean
7  a  0.327473       0.284001
8  a  0.240529       0.284001
0  b  0.099245       0.190927
2  b  0.239556       0.190927
3  b  0.211645       0.190927
6  b  0.213261       0.190927
1  c  0.081244       0.166271
4  c  0.256624       0.166271
5  c  0.091649       0.166271
9  c  0.235569       0.166271
```

So, going back to your example:

```
# setting up the data as a dataframe instead of a series, with 'measurement' column
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

stations = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dates    = pd.date_range(start = '2000-01-01', end = '2009-12-31')
index    = [(stations[i], dates[j]) for i in range(len(stations)) for j in range(len(dates))]
index    = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index, names=["station", "date"])

x        = np.random.random(len(index))

df       = pd.DataFrame(index = index, data = x, columns=['measurement'])

# create a new boolean column which will indicate if a particular measurement
# is above the average measurement for the same day of year across the dataset
df['above_average'] = df\
        .groupby(df.index.get_level_values('date').dayofyear)\
        .measurement\
        .transform(lambda x: x > x.mean())
```

The expression for `df['above_average']` reads: for each grouped dataframe (ie for each dataframe for each dayofyear), for each row, is the row value greater than the average value of the column within the group df? 
Once you have this boolean column calculated, you can easily get the number of days for each year that were above average:

```
df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values('date').year).above_average.mean()
```

Out

```
date
2000    0.478142
2001    0.515068
2002    0.508676
2003    0.466667
2004    0.534608
2005    0.518721
2006    0.478539
2007    0.484932
2008    0.467213
2009    0.509589
Name: above_average, dtype: float64
```

You can also get the overall average of days that were above day-of-year average:

```
df.above_average.mean()
```

Out

```
0.49621315813486633
```

**EDIT**: 
To get number rather than mean, use `sum()` instead of `mean()` as your aggregate function. Getting this count by station/year is a matter of grouping by those values.

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.groupby(['station', df['date'].dt.year]).above_average.sum()
```

Out

```
station  date
a        2000    193
         2001    175
         2002    181
         2003    177
         2004    163
         2005    183
         2006    200
         2007    178
         2008    180
         2009    176
b        2000    159
         2001    185
         2002    186
         2003    170
         2004    188
         2005    176
         2006    190
         2007    175
         2008    185
         2009    171
c        2000    183
         2001    186
         2002    194
         2003    178
         2004    181
         2005    187
         2006    185
         2007    169
         2008    195
         2009    175
Name: above_average, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! It is still not quite what I'm looking for though. First of all, this gives me the mean of above-average days, but I need the *number* of above average days. Also, I need number of days for each year that were above average *for each station individually*. I.e., the number of above average days for station 'a', the number of above average days for station 'b', etc

Comment: edited with more explanation

Comment: I believe there is another bug. I am looking for each station to be compared to the average for that station, not the average of all stations. I believe the lambda function as is compares a value to to average of all stations?

Comment: Ok, I was able to get what I wanted by changing your line `df['above_average'] = df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values('date').dayofyear)...` to `df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values('date').dayofyear, df.index.get_level_values('station')])`. This takes a very very long time to run on my data with ~5000 stations though! :/

Comment: Grouping by a high cardinality field is going to be slow. You can try converting your station to categorical data type so that pandas can represent it with an integer code, instead of grouping by a string field.

Comment: Not sure exactly what "converting your station to categorical data type" means. Station 'a' becomes 1, 'b' becomes 2, etc.?